# Fastapi how to add variable to all router with TemplateResponse

Tags: fastapi, starlette

I use JinjaTemplate and return data to html this way

```
@router.get('/', response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def main_page(request: Request,
                    members: List = [e.value for e in MembersQuantity],
                    activity_service: ActivityService = Depends(),
                    ):
    activity = await activity_service.get()
    return templates.TemplateResponse('base.html',
                                      context={
                                          'request': request,
                                          'members': members,
                                          'activities': activity,
                                      }
                                      )
```

There are dozens of such routs in the project. And each of them needs to have the same context variable.  I need to pass variables in all the routers - for example `user`.

I can write this way of passing the `user` object (it store in Redis)

```
@router.get('/', response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def main_page(request: Request,
                    members: List = [e.value for e in MembersQuantity],
                    activity_service: ActivityService = Depends(),
                    ):
    activity = await activity_service.get()
    user = None
    if await is_authenticated(request):
        user = await get_current_user(request)
    return templates.TemplateResponse('base.html',
                                      context={
                                          'request': request,
                                          'members': members,
                                          'activities': activity,
                                          'user': user,
                                      }
                                      )
```

**template**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Item Details</title>
    <link href="{{ url_for('static', path='/styles.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
     <a class="" href="{{ url_for('user_notification', pk=user.user_id) }}">
</body>
</html>
```

But doing it in every router is completely wrong.

I know of different ways to pass global variables using `middleware` in `request.state` or `response.set_cookie`. But this methods are not suitable for security reasons.

How can I globally transfer the value I want to the `context` for all the routs?

Comment: You could likely create a [dependency](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/) function and reuse it across the endpoints.

Comment: Nice, try this way/